# Does each individual sound require an instance of AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, avaudioplayer

I have a few game sounds, such as four different beep tones, and each one is played depending on the action the user performs.  Do I need to instantiate four different `AVAudioPlayer` objects?

Or do I just need one main player?  If I just need one, then how do I switch the file URL?

This is what I am doing now:

```
NSError *error;
soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:markedSound error:&error];
```

but it seems to take a few seconds to initialize. Is there a way to preload the files and switch between them quickly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continue creating as many instance as you have sounds.
After initialization, use the method `prepareToPlay`:

> Prepares the audio player for playback by preloading its buffers.
>   Discussion Calling this method preloads buffers and acquires the audio
>   hardware needed for playback, which minimizes the lag between calling
>   the `play` method and the start of sound output.
>
> Calling the `stop` method, or allowing a sound to finish playing, undoes
>   this setup.

For example:

```
NSError *error;
soundPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:markedSound error:&error];
[soundPlayer prepareToPlay];
```

For the moments, you only need 4 songs, so this would be premature optimization. But if later, the number of sounds you need increase a lot, you can wrap all this in a sub-class and do lazy loading. As the documentation states, using the `stop` method is the equivalent of unloading your file.

Answer (score -1):

You don't necessarily need to instantiate four different `AVAudioPlayer` objects, although this is one option (that may be simplest if you *only* have four sounds).

One you could make would be to load the sounds into memory in advance, which you can do by using the `initWithData` method instead of the `initWithContentsOfURL` (having loaded all your sound files in advance to `NSData` objects). This may speed things up slightly, although it also depends on your sound format. Uncompressed files will obviously be loaded much quicker than an MP3, for example.

If this still doesn't work out for you, your best bet would be to look at some of the lower level audio technologies provided, which are more suited for games work (OpenAL, Audio Toolbox, etc), but these are a fair bit more complex than a simple `AVVAudioPlayer`.

Comment: Solution not really optimal. I haven't checked, but I wouldn't be surprise if most of the delay comes from AVAudioPlayer doing its work (decompression...) rather than the file loading. And the lower lever solution can be great, but is a bit overkill in this situation.

Comment: Well, like I said, if you use uncompressed files it will be a lot quicker.